# How to add a layout into a layout in android

Tags: android

I don't know how to write code to add a layout into a layout in android, because when I read the reference, I saw it only have "AddView" method, when I try to use "AddView" method to add a layout, it don't work. Can you suggest me some solutions, I don't use XML file to add layout?

Comment: any reason in particular you are doing this with Java rather than xml?

Comment: 9 questions on SO and not one answer selected?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it don't work"? It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet that creates a new layout (newL), adds an image to it, and then adds newL to a layout (layout) that was defined in the XML

```
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp_fullWidth = 
        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(lWidth, lHeight);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp_wrap = 
        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, lHeight);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewNowPlaying);
    LinearLayout newL = new LinearLayout(context);    // create layout
    ImageView arrowRT = new ImageView(context);   // create image
    arrowRT.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrowrt); // set source file
    newL.addView(arrowRT, lp_wrap);               // add image to newL
    layout.addView(newL,lp_fullWidth);            // add newL to layout
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that exactly I want to find